# How can you get a XAML TextBlock in WP7 Silverlight to collapse when it contains no data?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a textblock inside a list view that I need to hide or collapse when it is empty or null. I tried using a string converter but that does not do it.

Any other ideas?

Update # 1:
Here is the code inside the textblock:

```
Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringConverter}}
```

Here is the converter:

```
public class StringConverter : IValueConverter
  {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
      {
          return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
      CultureInfo culture)
      {
          return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
      }

  }
```

Comment: Please show your code. Is it possible to filter a datasource before binding?

Comment: after posting the code, I realized my mistake. Thank you all for the answers. Here is the code                                                  Visibility="{Binding Description, Converter={StaticResource StringConverter}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating text and visibility bindings on your textbox.

Here's an example of the view model properties you'd have.

```
public String TextBoxText
{
    get { return textBoxText; }
    set
    {
        if (value != textBoxText)
        {
            textBoxText= value;
            SetTextBoxVisibility();
            OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxText");
        }
    }
}
private String textBoxText;

public Visibility TextBoxVisibility
{
    get { return textBoxVisibility; }
    set
    {
        if (value != textBoxVisibility)
        {
            textBoxVisibility= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxVisibility");
        }
    }
}
private Visibility textBoxVisibility;

public void SetTextBoxVisibility()
{
    this.TextBoxVisibility = String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextBoxText) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Why do you recommend doing this over a converter?  I'd only do that if the performance impact of having the converter was affecting overall performance. Typically there are a lot of other things that can impact performance and can be improved without the overhead of creating extra properties for every place where you would use such a converter. But I'm curious to hear your reasoning.

Comment: Good question, early on we started out with converters, but we quickly found that by leveraging the MVVM pattern our members became much easier to unit test and debugging was more intuitive, as opposed to the many generalized converters we'd created.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you've not shown of your code is where you instantiate the converter class. Is this because you're not doing so?

Typically you'd add something like this to app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <conv:StringConverter x:Key="StringConverter " />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```